Find a string and include character to a specific position
I have requirement to automate Azure wiki page with readme files via github actions.
I have my readme files in several paths in github repo.
"/community/widgets/document-details/readme.md"
"/.pipeline/readme.md"
"/examples/widgets/conference-session/readme"
I need to pull all the paths, get the contents of the readme file and look for .png strings.
png string are updated in format inside readme files.

Once I get all the png strings i need to replace it as below so that it is recognized in Azure wiki.

I am struggling to make this work using Get-Item, Get-content and for loop.
Please help me with scripts
$Path = "/community/widgets/document-details/readme.md","/.pipeline/readme.md" 
$OldText = "image.png"
$NewText = "/.attachments/$OldText" 
ForEach ($item in $Path) {
  $content = Get-Content $Path | Where-Object {$_ -like '.png'} 
  Write-Host "content list is "$content 
  foreach ($entry in $content) {
    Write-Host $entry 
    $entry -replace $OldText, $NewText 
  } 
  Set-Content $Path 
}


Please update your question with the relevant code :)

updated the code above.Please help

are you looking for any .png link or specifically for image.png ?

it is for any .png link. So png names length will differ in size

ok, i think my answer should accomplish what you're up to

If I understand correctly you're looking to prepend /.attachments/ to any .png Markdown link, if that's the case, you could use the pattern (?<=\]\()(?=.+\.png\)) and replace with /.attachments/.
An example below:
$text = @'
text text text ![foo](foo.png)
![bar](bar.png) text text text
text ![baz](baz.png) text text
'@

$text -replace '(?<=\]\()(?=.+\.png\))', '/.attachments/'

# Outputs:
#
# text text text ![foo](/.attachments/foo.png)
# ![bar](/.attachments/bar.png) text text text
# text ![baz](/.attachments/baz.png) text text

Applied to your code:
$Path = '/community/widgets/document-details/readme.md', '/.pipeline/readme.md'

foreach ($item in $Path) {
    (Get-Content $item -Raw) -replace '(?<=\]\()(?=.+\.png\))', '/.attachments/' |
        Set-Content $item
}

See https://regex101.com/r/NbyUnq/3 for regex details.

Thanks for the answer!! The prepend pattern works perfectly if I use only one entry in Path. If i run it in a loop, the png file gets updated as (/.attachments//.attachments/image) and also the contents of all readme files entry gets appended as one.

@user25393641 i'm not sure i follow your comment, it seems you're processing the files more than once? it might be a good idea to move the files already processed to a different folder in that case

Thanks for your suggestions. I have one more requiremment in addition to the above one.
After image dir changes the current image entry in the readme file is updated as ![bar](dir/folder1/image.png). I need to delete the dir/folder1 part and then prepend the "./attachments". So the updated image entry will look like ![bar](./attachments/image.png). Any advise for this?

@user25393641 it is doable but new requirements should be asked in a new question. you can reference this answer if needed

I made it work using this -replace './dir/folder1/', '' -replace '(?<=\]\().+\.png', '/.attachments/$0' . Thanks for all the help!!

@user25393641 glad you could sort it out. if you have further questions feel free to ask a new one referencing this Q&A
